# How to calculate sum of output values over the terminal in linux

Tags: bash, text-processing

We have output as in the example below and want to calculate the total size of it in one line:

```
[root@test01]# vgs | awk '{print $6}'
VSize
46.58g
179.99g
99.99g
```

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange ! It is customary when you are satisfied with an answer (as you seem to be here) to mark it as accepted with a green check mark situated to the left of the answer directly under its score. Your helper will receive karma points and the rest of the community will automatically know that that answer is valid and can be re-used. Only OP can check the green mark.  Cheers !

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution would be to adjust the `vgs` output to print result in bytes without the header and unit suffix and then you can use `bc` to calculate the sum:

```
$ sudo vgs -o size --unit=b --no-suffix --no-headings
  10737418240
  20396900352
   1069547520

$ sudo vgs -o size --unit=b --no-suffix --no-headings | paste -s -d+ - | bc
32203866112
```

Comment: vgs -o size --unit=G --no-suffix --no-headings | paste -s -d+ - | bc
350.66
This works well really apricate your help on this. :-)